# Find $\int_a^b(f(x)-g(x))\mathrm{d}x$ if $f(x)=x^{x^{1-x}}$ and $g(x)$ is the linear equation from the extrema $(a,f(a))$, $(b,f(b))$ of $f(x)∀x≥0$.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, area, lambert-w

Find $\int_a^b(f(x)-g(x))\mathrm{d}x|$ if $f(x)=x^{x^{1-x}}$ and $g(x)$ is the linear equation from the extrema $(a,f(a))$, $(b,f(b))$ of $f(x)∀x≥0$.

Find the exact area.
The area under $g(x)$ as negative and the area above $g(x)$ is positive.

#### How I (tried to) solve it

1. I found the x-coordinates of the extrema using $f'(x)=-x^{x^{1-x}-x}(x\ln(x)-1)(\ln(x)+1)=0$; $x=a,b=e^{-1},e^\Omega$ where $\Omega$ represents the omega constant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant.
2. I plugged the x-coordinates into $f(x)$ to get the extrema. I got $(e^{-1},e^{-e^{e^{-1}-1}})$ and $(e^{\Omega},e^{e^{-1}})$.
3. I then got $g(x)$ with the two points; $g\left(x\right)=\frac{e^{1+e^{-1}}-e^{1-e^{e^{-1}-1}}}{e^{\Omega+1}-1}x-\frac{e^{e^{-1}}-e^{1-e^{e^{-1}-1}+\Omega}}{e^{1+\Omega}-1}$.
   Note that I simplified it *a lot* to get it down to this.
4. To find the area, I did

$\int_a^b(f(x)-g(x))\mathrm{d}x=\int_{e^{-1}}^{e^\Omega}(f(x)-g(x))\mathrm{d}x=F(e^{\Omega})-G(e^{\Omega})-(F(e^{-1})-G(e^{-1}))$ where $F$ and $G$ represent the antiderivatives of their respective functions. Unfortunately, here is where I got stuck because I could not find the antiderivative of $f(x)$ (as I am only in Calc AB). I did, however, put it into Desmos and got the value $0.0369975757242$. What is the exact value?

Desmos "solution": https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yzzhqdptb4

Also, I know this might be a little confusing to read so editing is greatly appreciated if necessary. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the answer, just some remarks: $g$ is *linear* and therefore can be integrated easily. $f$ has no antiderivative in terms of elementary functions. If that problem has an “exact solution” then perhaps the definite integral can be computed using some properties of these particular bounds.

Comment: Thanks for catching the mistake with $g$ being linear. I was able to get that antiderivative easily. By "some properties of these particular bounds", do you mean because the bounds involve $e$ to some power?

Comment: What I mean is that sometimes a definite integral can be computed even if there is no “explicit” antiderivative known, e.g. using symmetries or clever substitutions.

Comment: Thank you ! I enjoy the approximation with $\Omega$ in it.

Comment: And thank you so much for solving it! I'm glad you enjoyed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make a series expansion around $x=1$, you have
$$f(x)-g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n\,(x-1)^n$$ where
$$\alpha_0=\frac{e^{1-e^{\frac{1}{e}-1}} (\Omega-1)-\Omega-(e-1) e^{\frac{1}{e}}   \Omega+e}{e-\Omega}$$
$$\alpha_1=1+\frac{e \left(e^{-e^{\frac{1}{e}-1}}-e^{\frac{1}{e}}\right)
  \Omega}{e-\Omega}$$ and the next coefficients form the sequence
$$\left\{0,-1,0,\frac{7}{12},\frac{1}{6},-\frac{169}{360},-\frac{29}{72
   0},\frac{589}{2520},\frac{253}{5040},-\frac{11959}{75600},-\frac{131}{302400},\cdots\right\}$$
$$\int_{\frac 1 e}^{\frac 1 \Omega} \big[f(x)-g(x)\big]\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n\,\frac{\left(\frac{1}{\Omega
   }-1\right)^{n+1}-\left(\frac{1}{e}-1\right)^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

I only gave the first twelve coefficients but the next are easy to generate. Computing the partial sums
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & \sum_{n=0}^k \\
 10 & 0.0373722254885034 \\
 20 & 0.0369975152106470 \\
 30 & 0.0369975783245838 \\
 40 & 0.0369975758084201 \\
 50 & 0.0369975757271674 \\
 60 & 0.0369975757242847 \\
 70 & 0.0369975757241703 \\
 80 & 0.0369975757241654 \\
 90 & 0.0369975757241652 \\
 100 & 0.0369975757241652 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

With more decimals, the integral is
$$0.036997575724165175495421514762496185924469669290735\cdots$$ which not recognized by the $ISC$. But, what is proposed as a *"close closed"* form is
$$\color{blue}{\large\frac \Omega {10} \, K_1(1){}^{\sin (1)}}$$ which shows an absolute error of  $4.486\times 10^{-9}$.